# MVC .NET Web service no access to Sharepoint Site on deploy mode

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, sharepoint

I'm developing a web service MVC .NET application that access to a Sharepoint 2013 site, I'm using the Microsoft.Sharepoint.dll not the client dll. When I run my web service on VS2015 in the IIS Express in release and debug mode I don´t have any problem, but when I deploy the app to my local IIS the web service return an error

> The Web application at http://[URL to SharePoint]/ could not be found.

I've tried running it with different URL such as http://localhost/sites/mysite and by domain name http://domain/sites/mysite, and I got the same results, on my VS IIS Express runs without problems but on the deploy IIS not.

The app is running on Framework 4.5 and AnyCpu compilation, I've tried downgrading the framework to 3.5 but without success. What could be the problem?, Is there any special permissions on the VS IIS that I need to enable on my local IIS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved deploying my application on a new web site in the IIS with the same applicattion pool used by my Sharepoint web site